# Does informatica webservice workflow always allow concurrent execution

Tags: web-services, informatica, informatica-powercenter

We have exposed a workflow as webservice workflow in informatica. While configuring this, we can see that the option 'Concurrent execution' is enabled by default and there is no option to change it(option is grayed out). We don't want client to invoke a workflow while it is already running.
Basically workflow should not start again while it is in running state. How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Once the workflow is exposed as a service, it can be called multiple times from various clients. I don't think it's possible to prevent that via config, at least from what I can see in the [Creating a Web Service Workflow](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-2/web-services-provider-guide/working-with-web-service-workflows/creating-and-configuring-a-web-service-workflow/creating-a-web-service-workflow.html) document - it clearly states:

> When you enable the Web Services option, the Configure Concurrent
> Execution option is enabled by default. The web service workflow
> configuration properties include settings for concurrent execution of
> the web service.

[This subpage](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-2/web-services-provider-guide/working-with-web-service-workflows/creating-and-configuring-a-web-service-workflow/concurrent-execution-of-web-service-workflows.html) says it's controlled by Web Service Hub automatically.

> The Web Services Hub determines when to start a new instance of a web
> service workflow based on the availability of resources and values you
> set for the properties of the web service.

As a result, the only possible way seems to implement some logic in the Workflow itself, like

1. Check if an indicator file exists
2. Use Decision task:

   1. If indicator file is avaiable, end the workflow
   2. If indicator file does not exist, create it
3. Perform the rest of your logic
4. Final step: remove indicator file

Above shall result in any additional instance spotting the indicator file and simpli finishing the flow. The only problem would be if your workflow fails - the indicator file would persist. I will leave this open for you to try solving it. In case of problems, do not hesitate to show what you tried and ask for support.